# Flash Cs5 : Publishing Apps Limitations - can you make stand alone applications?

Tags: android, iphone, performance, actionscript-3, flash

I'm looking to explore the possibilities of publishing apps in Flash cs5 although, I was concerned with a the limitations or hidden pitfalls of using flash for this purpose. I'm designer and illustrator with some coding experience.

What is the ease of deployment for Android and the app store? is there any post flash stages that I would need to know about?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CS5 should work fine, but there are a few caveats: You will need to update your AIR compiler to the latest version, or you will not be able to make iPhone5 compatible apps. 
Hopefully you are on Windows, because in this case you can use FlashDevelop to publish your apps, and pair that with Flash CS5 for the art. I'd recommend this build process even if you are on a mac. But since Flash Develop is windows only, you'll need to run parallels or bootcamp or something to let you run the windows app. That will make development harder, but not impossible.

So: CS5 is OK. It does not support publishing apps out of the box (you need at least CS5.5 for that) But there are good (free) solutions avaiable that will pair with Flash CS5.

Comment: Hard to resist adding: if you value your time use FlashDevelop ( or something just like it) for coding your AS3. And, as much as I don't like the idea of rent-a-Flash (a.k.a. Flash CC) its cost might easily be made back, over a year, compared to app-building with CS5.

Comment: Cheers Plastic Surgeon - like the answer, although i'm running on a mac! Do you have any hints for the "free solutions"? In regards to CC, I agree. It does look the best, although it wouldn't be worth my time to invest in it just yet.

Comment: If you have more time than money, try finding a solution to run Flash develop on a mac. This guy claims to have it working with Parallels. 
http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=2463

But you will save yourself some heartache and trouble using either the latest FlashDevelop or Flash CC.

Comment: I might be able to give the Flash Develop a whirl on my retro laptop... which is running XP

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend getting Flash CC. If you are doing simple programming than CC would be fine and the code editor is somewhat better than previously, but more importantly things will mostly just work rather than issues you get when trying to setup and build with old versions of the Flash software and trying to publish to new versions of device software.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I'm running on Flash CC at work. I've not actively used App setting on CC yet. I was asking out of interest for the one I have at home, which is cs5.

Comment: Its possible to get cs5 publishing as has been mentioned since you are publishing via the SDK, but you might need to hack it more because cs5 does not support all the features of the latest AIR SDK. Its usually smoothest if you use the latest IDE to publish to the latest versions of platforms.

Comment: Thanks Dave... I think, I will have to invest in the future.